# Which option should I choose for exposing functionality?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class that handles communication with some device. I have called this class Protocol.
The class does not contain any state information, and thus I have created a model class that should expose the methods in the protocol class and contain the state of the device.

As I see it, there are three ways of implementing this

1. Let the model class inherit from the protocol
2. Let the model class implement the protocol
3. Let the model expose the protocol through a property

It could be that the protocol contains methods that are better left unexposed to the implementer of the model class which speaks against option 1 and 3.

Option 2 lets me choose which things I would like to expose from the protocol, but most of the functionality will just be calls to the protocol like:

```
DoSomething()
{
    protocol.DoSomething();
}
```

What do you think would be the "better" option?

N.B.: The reason for decoupling the state and the protocol, is that the protocol is not fixed, and can change depending on outside factors.

Comment: so why does the model talk to the protocol in the first place?

Comment: It holds the state of the device, and must have a way of retrieving that state.

Comment: Why would option 3 expose sensitive protocol methods to the aggregating class? Even option 1, which is usually a bad use of inheritance, may not end up exposing anything.

Comment: @Jon because it exposes the protocol itself. I agree that option 1 is fishy, but why wouldn't it end up exposing anything?

Comment: Ask yourself whether the model class "is a" protocol or whether it "has a" protocol. If it *is a* protocol, you want option 1. If it *has a* protocol, you want option 3. I think "protocol" isn't an appropriate name for your functionality, though - when I read "protocol" I think TCP/IP or HTTP. I'd go with option 3.

Comment: Edit: I'd go with option 3 - "has a" protocol but I'd use an interface that only exposes the members you want public rather than the class itself; then have the protocol class implement that interface. so the model class doesn't have a `Protocol` but rather a `IProtocol`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need an inheritance relation between them?

```
interface IDevice
{
    // Some implementation
}

interface IProtocol : IDisposable
{
    void Open(IDevice device, string connection);
    void Close();
    void Send(object data);
    object Receive();
}
```

Comment: No, not between the device and the protocol. The protocol just implements whatever the device understands. The protocol "lives" on top of a TCP connection or a RS-232 connection, depending on how the device is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I've used what we called a Command Handler design in the past for something like this, and this is how it worked:

There was a CommandHandler class (well, component really - it had several cooperating classes) that did all the work (what you referred to as ".DoSomething()".  So, this is the same as your Protocol Class above.  This CommandHandler class/component, however, did not know anything about the protocol.  He just used the native languages constructs (in your case C# classes/interfaces) to do the work.  Then, there would be one or more Protocol classes that did the work of converting the protocol to the languages constructs (for example, convert XML to messages classes, binary bytes from a stream to classes, etc) and execute features of the command handler component by creating instances of it's classes from the decoded protocol and passing arguments to these instances methods from parameters derived from the protocol.

To implement a new protocol for your command handler, write the protocol class and have it handle whatever protocol you want, having it create instances of and call the  methods of your Command Handler component that the other protocols did so that the core functionality doesn't change.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Well, not exactly. I am trying to decouple an existing protocol class from a class that holds the state of the device that supports the protocol.